# MongoDb date format

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native, bigdata

I was doing bulk insert into MongoDB using NodeJs (native -driver). I have date field in the data. Is there anyway to store the date field as `Date` rather than `String`?

I have date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. In current scenario I attain the result by iterating through the bulk data converting the date into `mm/dd/yyyy` format, then create new Date and save.

Since the iteration takes too much time as amount of Data increases; is there any other method to do it?

Comment: Can you share some code as to how you are doing the insert. I am not sure how you are getting the date from.

Comment: You need in any case to convert String to Date before inserting in DB. You might consider of updating only updated part of collection if documents do repeat from last to new bulk inserts. So you can update only the one that have been changed / added.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell mongodb (mongoimport) to convert the string 'dd/mm/yyyy' to a $date type during the import.

What you can do is to change the type after the bulk insert. You can run this code at the mongodb shell (mongo):

```
    db.your-collection-name.find().forEach(function(element){

       var parts = element.date.split("/");

       //reduce month by 1 because in javascript january is 0
       element.date = new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);

       db.your-collection-name.save(element);

    });
```